# Web Server (Intranet) Availability Test Script/Program

Tags: web-server, monitoring, http, test, http-status-code

After rebooting a number of web servers (around 40), I would like to be able to quickly test each one to ensure that they are all up, running and will return an HTTP 200 code when called.

Please can you suggest a script or tool to do this? I should be able to run it from my Windows PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**
Assuming the sites are all publicly available, it looks like you could also use this [service](http://www.seoconsultants.com/tools/headers-batch). All you'd need to do is maintain a text document of the sites to test in order to paste into the form, seems pretty simple.

**Original Message:**
You could whip something up on your own, I'm personally bias towards Ruby and have used it to check service status at the end of a maintenance window.

There's a script [here](http://www.example-code.com/ruby/http_getStatus.asp) that you could tweak a little, perhaps to pass an array of sites you want to check.

To do this from a Windows computer you'll also need to install Ruby, which is easy with the [One Click Ruby Installer](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubyinstaller/).

I hope that's helpful, let me know if you need any help with the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that can do this sort of monitoring, from [What's Up Gold](http://www.whatsupgold.com/) to [The Dude](http://www.mikrotik.com/thedude.php) to a simple shell script like the one mentioned in Curt's answer. If you let us know what tools/languages are available to you and you are familiar with, we can provide some more examples (e.g. do you have access to bash, powershell, python, etc.; are you familiar with any programming languages, or you want a simple point and click interface?). Depending on the situation, I've used all of the above at times, and they all work to varying degrees with varying degrees of effort (and repeatability).

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly easy to do with the Nagios plugin check_http.

Comment: Nagios looks okay, but from the website it looks like it needs to be hosted on Linux PC's. I want to monitor from a Windows PC. Thanks.